# AndroidNotification small icon not showing in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, icons, display

I'm trying to set a custom small icon for notifications in my Flutter app using the flutter_local_notifications package and Firebase Cloud Messaging. I've already set the large icon successfully, but for some reason the small icon isn't showing up. Here's the relevant code:

```
  Future<void> _registerForegroundMessageHandler() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      AndroidNotification? android = remoteMessage.notification?.android;

      print(" --- foreground message received ---");
      print(remoteMessage.notification!.title);
      print(remoteMessage.notification!.body);
      String smallIcon = 'drawable/small_launcher_icon';
      AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
          AndroidNotificationDetails('channel_id', 'channel_name',
              importance: Importance.high,
              priority: Priority.high,
              ticker: 'New message received',
              icon: smallIcon,
              playSound: true,
              enableVibration: true,
              styleInformation: const DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
              //sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
              largeIcon:
                  const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('mipmap/launcher_icon'),
              //color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
              ledColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
              ledOnMs: 1000,
              ongoing: true,
              ledOffMs: 500);
      NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
          NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

      // Display the notification
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, // Notification ID
        remoteMessage.notification?.title ?? 'default title',
        remoteMessage.notification?.body ?? 'default body',
        notificationDetails,
      );
    });
  }
```

I've tried setting the smallIcon path to both 'mipmap/launcher_icon' and '@mipmap/launcher_icon', but neither works. I also tried clearing the app cache and reinstalling, but that didn't help either. Interestingly, the large icon displays correctly, so I know that the icon file exists in the correct location.

What else could be causing the small icon to not show up? How can I fix this issue?